# На всемирном экономическом кризисе

Tags: оговорки

"На всемирном экономическом кризисе в Давосе". 
Копирайты - CNN минуту назад.
Вопрос. Почему это смешно? Нет, правда, какова природа этого "юмора"?
Кстати, есть еще подобные из числа свежих? Я когда-то их собирал пачками...

Comment: Я бы задал вопрос, почему это НЕ смешно.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, тут речь не о кризисе, а о конгрессе.
А вообще, я такие вещи тоже собираю. И на тему той же безграмотности в вывесках, рекламе и интернете у меня большая коллекция фотографий и скриншотов. Уже давно мечтаю поделиться, но здесь вроде как не формат)))

Comment: >По-моему, тут речь не о кризисе, а о конгрессе.  
  
Ну да. Иначе бы и моего вопроса не было.

Answer (score 0):

Смешно потому, что обычно не кто-то на кризисе, а кризис на ком-то. Ведь имеет он, а не его.

Answer (score 0):

Из свежего. Сегодня на телеканале РБК: "В США разбился истребитель. Летчику удалось капитулироваться".

Comment: Видимо, Меркурий близко к Земле.